# How to avoid Error: "response status 404, message "Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm running selenium tests with complex data. When the test with 1st data completed successfully, before launch test with 2nd data i get this Error:

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x04638850>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"Unable to locate element: [id=\\"username\\"]...ror@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:389:5\\nelement.find/</<@chrome://marionette/content/element.js:339:16\\n"}}'}
```

Comment: More detailed code would help and the exact point of error. Seems like you are trying to find element that doesn't exist on the page

Comment: You are probably trying to locate the element before it's been loaded.  look into `support.expected_conditions` so the page waits for the element before interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

when you launch test with 2nd, the HTML don't have a element of '[id=\"username\"]'
you should wait 2nd HTML load the element of '[id=\"username\"]'

there is solution wait the 2nd HTML element

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '[id=\\"username\\"]')))
```